# Windows 7 as office web / file sharing server - are there any licence restrictions?

Tags: iis, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

I am working for a small company (15 computers) and we would like to use Windows 7 Professional as internal file sharing and Web Server (IIS 7.5, ASP.NET / SQL Server intranet application).

Are there any licence restrictions that forbid using Windows 7 in that way ?

Answer (score 1):

There are no licensing issues, but there are limitations.  Windows 7 only allows 20 users to be logged into the file shares at once - you can see this limit if you run "net config server" from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no licence restrictions. You can do whatever you want with your Windows. IIS is included with Windows 7 Pro, ASP.NET is made by Microsoft and SQL Server also.

Internal sharing, I guess you mean using Microsoft Network ? You can, it's a feature of Windows. You could also use an FTP or something else.

You can do pretty what you want, even more if it's in an internal network like you said.

Answer (score 0):

No, but there are limits.  Win 7 is limited to 20 connections (but I can't find a source for that other than this: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/1102-63-inbound-connections-limit-windows)